# REGEX find all text within custom tags

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I would like to create a Gmail application that captures all text within this custom tag `<! some text, blah, blah, blah >`

The tag is  `<! text_to_be_captured_here >`

What pattern might I use. Of course the text within the tag is variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and someone churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are planning to create the said application using Google Apps Script as you have included **google-apps-script** tag while posting the question.

Assuming you already have taken input of the text and stored it in the variable **string**, please try code given below:

```
var string = "Here is some random text that you received as input from your <!Gmail Application>";

var requiredText = "Custom Tag not found!";

if(string.match(/\<\!(.*?)\>/))
{
  requiredText = string.match(/\<\!(.*?)\>/).pop().trim();
}

Logger.log("Text withing custom tag :"+requiredText);
```

If the output in the log is **Custom Tag not found!** then the string that you've entered does not contain the pre-defined custom tag.

If it is anything other than **Custom Tag not found!** then the it means the code is working.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx Much Suyash !